# Нужно вычесть разницу чисел одного столбца агрегируя по двум другим столбцам

Tags: sql, sql-server

Таблица для примера
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно вычесть разницу рейтинга (Rating) агрегируя по дате и фио записывая   результат в соседний столбец (Reit_Dyn), Если у Сидорова на 2019-10-11 рейтинг 4, а 2019-09-30 - 6 то то в соседний пишем 2, если данных нету за предыдущую дату то записываем 0.

Comment: "записуя" - +1!

Comment: версия СУБД ?..

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 13.0.4001.0 (X64)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

среди оконных функций с 2012й версии есть `lag` и `lead`, позволяющие получать доступ к предыдущим/следующим строкам выборки.

так что если ваши исходные данные (*а на будущее, будьте добры, давать код для генерации схемы, а не картинку*) выглядят следующим образом:

```
declare @sample table (id int identity, d DATE, name varchar(10), rating INT, dyn INT);

INSERT INTO @sample (d, name, rating) values
('2019-10-11', 'Сидоров', 4),
('2019-10-11', 'Петренко',2),
('2019-10-11', 'Иванов',  5),
('2019-09-30', 'Сидоров', 6),
('2019-09-30', 'Петренко',7),
('2019-09-30', 'Иванов',  14),
('2019-08-31', 'Сидоров', 11),
('2019-08-31', 'Петренко',2),
('2019-08-31', 'Иванов',  3);
```

то `lag(rating, 1, null)` получит значение в предыдущей строке. Если такового не было, то вернем `null`. И если в CTE у нас не null, то считаем разницу, если же null, то зануляем.

```
;with data as (
    select id, d, name, rating, dyn
    , LAG(rating,1, null) over (partition by name order by d asc) as x
    FROM @sample
    --order by name, d desc
)

update data 
set dyn = case when x is null then 0 else x - rating end;
```

результатом будет

```
id          d          name       rating      dyn
----------- ---------- ---------- ----------- -----------
3           2019-10-11 Иванов     5           9
6           2019-09-30 Иванов     14          -11
9           2019-08-31 Иванов     3           0
2           2019-10-11 Петренко   2           5
5           2019-09-30 Петренко   7           -5
8           2019-08-31 Петренко   2           0
1           2019-10-11 Сидоров    4           2
4           2019-09-30 Сидоров    6           5
7           2019-08-31 Сидоров    11          0
```